# Ajax Request PrototypeJS

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I can't understand AJAX using PrototypeJS ("prototype.js" in the same folder of the program). In a php file I have a button which recall a javascript function. In this function I do an Ajax request passing the URL of another php file, which connects to a mysql database. But when I click the button, nothing happens.
I get no errors on the console

php file with the button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <button type="button" id="stampa" onClick="stampa()"> Stampa </button>

        <script src="prototype.js"></script>
        <script>
            function stampa()
            {
                new Ajax.Request('http://localhost:8888/Prova_AJAX/query_3_php.php');
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

php file which connects to the database:

```
<?php

    #connect to database
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $db_name = "Chat";

    try
    {
        $db = new PDO("mysql: host=$servername; dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connection established";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        die;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Looks like `Ajax.Request` is just a constructor for a `Request`, similar to the `Request` in the Fetch API. It just represents the request, it doesn’t automatically send one. Have you opened the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors?

Comment: *"But when I click the button, nothing happens."* No, when you click the button, you get an error in the web console. The reason you get that error is that you've included jQuery, not PrototypeJS, in the page, but you're trying to use `new Ajax.Request`, which is a PrototypeJS feature. Use the correct lib (in 2018 that probably wouldn't be PrototypeJS), or no lib, and use that lib's functions (or ones built-into the browser, like [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch)).

Comment: Please be sure to tag correctly. You used [tag:prototype], but you meant [tag:prototypejs] (also, [tag:php] isn't relevant; your question is about making the request in the JavaScript code).

Comment: @Xufox - Oh, that's a **very** handy link. Bookmarked. :-)